# Intertwining two letters in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

I'm interested in intertwining two letters that are labels of two nodes; or converting the shape of the letters to two paths (much like the feature in Inkscape with the same name) which I can then intertwine like in this example of the Borromean rings: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/borromean-rings/

Here's my MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray!60] (0,0) circle (2);
 \node[color=black!80] 
at (0.25,-0.25) 
{\fontsize{60}{20}\fontfamily{ppl}\fontseries{b}\selectfont C};
\node[color=yellow!50] 
at (-0.25,0.25) 
{\fontsize{60}{20}\fontfamily{ppl}\fontseries{b}\selectfont Q};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I want is for the C to "pass above" the Q on the uppermost intersection, while it passes below it on the lower one. I attach a picture of what I want, made haphazardly with Pinta.

[image: Desired result.]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not a general solution, but you could just draw the black letter twice, but clip it the second time so that only the part that you want is drawn:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[gray!60] (0,0) circle (2);
  \node[color=black!80, font=\fontsize{60}{20}\fontfamily{ppl}\fontseries{b}\selectfont]
    at (0.25,-0.25) {C};
  \node[color=yellow!50, font=\fontsize{60}{20}\fontfamily{ppl}\fontseries{b}\selectfont] 
    at (-0.25,0.25) {Q};
  \clip (0,0) -- (0:2) arc (0:90:2) -- cycle;
  \node[color=black!80, font=\fontsize{60}{20}\fontfamily{ppl}\fontseries{b}\selectfont]
    at (0.25,-0.25) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Quite elegant! Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

This is just a minor addendum to [David Purton's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530893/194703). Some may feel more comfortable just specifying how much of the character should be cut. As long as this is some distance from either of its boundaries, `trimclip` can do the job (and in principle you would not need `tikz` then). And it is usually a good idea to use the `font` or `node font` key to set the font, and `circle[radius=2]` instead of `circle(2)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\fontsize{60}{20}\fontfamily{ppl}\fontseries{b}\selectfont]
 \fill[gray!60] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
 \node[color=black!80,below] at (0.25,1.25) {C};
 \node[color=yellow!50] at (-0.25,0.25) {Q};
 \node[color=black!80,below] at (0.25,1.25) {\clipbox{0em 0.5em 0em 0em}{C}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would still have to figure out how `\clipbox` works, but this looks rather nicer and more compact. Thanks!